# Pygame repetitive backgrounds

Tags: performance, pygame

Consider a situation where we have e.g. a bar that is the width of the screen. Which one is more efficient:

1) make a narrow sprite for the bar and draw that piece many times

2) make a wide sprite for the bar and draw a larger piece fewer times

The operations here would be to `load` a smaller or larger image once independent of which case is chosen, and to `blit` that smaller or larger image more times in 1 than in 2.

Generally, I have run into a lot of cases where repetitive backgrounds are, ahem, repeated. But I also hear that the `blit` operation is slow.

Answer (score 0):

You kind of answered your own question, blit is slow, personally I'd use Sprites cause then you draw without the use of blit, but assuming you do use blit, it would be faster to have a larger image and blit it to the screen fewer times, less calls to blit is better. Also one thing to remember is to speed up blit make sure you convert the surface.

```
surface = pygame.Surface((100,100))
surface.convert()
```

Comment: *blit is slow, personally I'd use Sprites cause then you draw without the use of blit* that does not make sense. A Sprite ist just a wrapper class around a Surface. To draw a Sprite you still blit its Surface to the screen.